# Docker totally filling my space in disk and killing my machine

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I am with a problem when I running docker in production.
The space in disk are filling and stop the working of machine.
[this image show the result of "df -h" command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGgTE.png)

I can erase this files? It's possible work with docker without making this files?

Thanks

Comment: You typically make `/var/lib/docker` a separate filesystem so that if it fills up it doesn't impact anything other than docker. The space is primarily consumed by docker images...if you have limited space, you'll need to be careful about what images you pull, and you should delete ones you're no longer using.

Comment: You can set the data-root in your daemon.json file to a much bigger drive or disk as usually /var would not have much space. once you set perform daemon reload and restart docker service.  Docker will smoothly copy all your volume data to your new data root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have done docker installation. and your storage is mapped to default /var. Which I believe will hold very less space unless you have manually allotted.
Do a df -kh on your device and see the status of the device mapped to /var. You would have run out of space.
To fix this find a disk with good space - remember this will be used by docker to store all its image and volume data. and make the docker use it.
You need to configure this in daemon.json file as a data-root config like below.
{ “data-root”: “/new/data/root/path” }
Remember to reload the daemon and restart docker service. Once done you will see docker beautifully copies its image and volume data to the new directory.
once you test you can clean up the var/lib/docker.
Hope this helps